# How to find process name to attach to a windows service?

Tags: windows-services

I have a Windows Service "MyNewService", I want to debug this service by attaching the breakpoint only.

It can be done using visual studio 2010 as per below steps :
1. Go to Tools --> Attach To Process --> "Process Name of service"

I don't know which process to attach for my service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the imagepath of your Windows Service with this command:

```
sc qc MyNewService
```

for `eventlog` it will output:

```
SERVICE_NAME: eventlog  
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS  
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START  
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL  
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetw orkRestricted
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : Event Log
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Windows Event Log
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : NT AUTHORITY\LocalService
```

You are interested in the **BINARY_PATH_NAME** value

Comment: I am not able to find 
sc qc MyNewService 
Getting "The specified service does not exist as an installed service."

If I go to Run --> Services.msc 
I can see name as MyNewService.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I am able to find BINARY_PATH_NAME for MyNewService.

But which process name to attach in visual studio ?